# Excel formula to match first 3 digits in 2 columns

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 columns of numbers in Excel.  I want to match first 3 digits of column A with the first 3 numbers of column B and if they are the same, in column C I need to fill in the data `same` if not then `not same`. I have a list of 16 thousand entries in Excel and need a quick way to figure this out.

eg.

```
A1: 810123 B1: 810567 then column c should say "same" because the first 3 numbers match.
A2: 801123 B2: 803123 then column c should say "notsame" because the first 3 numbers do not match.
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IF()` and `LEFT()` formulas for this:

```
=IF(Left(A1, 3) = Left(B1, 3), "same", "not same")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MID(text, start_indx, length)` which can return first three digits. I have use `if` statement to test first three digits of columns. If they are equal it put `same` on the cell else `notsame`. In result column put this formula.

```
=IF(MID(A1,1,3)=MID(B1,1,3),"same","notsame")
```

Comment: could you please accompany your code with some text that explains it :) ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.  This method worked as well :)